# Is there a single-line solution for an array of OrderedDictionary keys?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a single-line solution for getting the keys of a OrderedDictionary. I already got a working solution by using the following method, but is there a way to use less code to achieve the same thing by using LINQ for instance?

```
private string[] GetKeys(OrderedDictionary orderedDictionary)
{
    List<string> keyList = new List<string>(orderedDictionary.Count);

    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in orderedDictionary)
    {
        keyList.Add(entry.Key.ToString());
    }

    return keyList.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `orderedDictionary.Keys`?

Comment: Efficient in what way? Efficient in memory usage? Efficient in CPU usage? Efficient in readability? Efficient in typing?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Are you asking "How can I make this code run faster and with less memory?" or are you asking "How can I write this code more simply?" Most programmers think of the first question when you ask how to make code more efficient. But I think you are really asking the second question.

Comment: @Buddy I tried that :) That seems to work for dictionaries, but not for ordered dictionaries

Comment: I suggest you familiarize yourself with the MSDN documentation. In particular, OrderedDictionary already has a Keys property that does exactly what you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.keys?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Specialized_OrderedDictionary_Keys

Comment: @C-137 What do you mean it [doesn't work for `OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.keys?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: @Amy I meant to say that the the keys property of a ordered dictionary returns a different object than the dictionary

Comment: @C-137 well of course.  It's a collection of only the keys, not a collection of keys and values.  Why is that a problem?  How is the `keyList` in your question any different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this for less code -

```
var myKeys = orderedDictionary.Keys.Cast<string>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Code-Apprentice was right, I should have looked at the MSDN documentation.
The following code was found there and does what I was looking for.

```
string[] myKeys = new string[orderedDictionary.Count];
orderedDictionary.Keys.CopyTo(myKeys, 0);
```